# What does it mean to Port?

Tags: tokens

eg. Ether holders have a strong economic incentive to take any token protocol that works and port it directly to Ether.

Comment: Do you have a source for the above sentence? Might help if we have the overall context.

Comment: ...The more interesting economic force, in my opinion, is that Ether holders have a strong economic incentive to take any token protocol that works and port it directly to Ether. Let’s say Filecoin gets 30% of the Ethereum market cap. If Ether holders successfully port it — a simple matter of copying the code of the smart contracts — they absorb that value, and the value of their Ether goes up. So it seems like it will be tried. The question is whether or not it will work. In cases where a token is really needed for the reasons described above, I think the answer is no.

Comment: Generally, it means to rewrite the software for a target platform. So, "port the app to Windows, or port the coin to Solidity."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port in this context means to 'migrate'. The author of that statement is saying that there is no need to build a blockchain solution independent of Ethereum blockchain because once a solution is proven to be workable enough, Ethereum holders can simply recreate that solution on Ethereum and leverage the network effect of Ethers.

If Filecoin is a protocol which pays people for providing HDD space, then Ethereum developers can rebuild it on Ethereum networks while paying Ethers to people providing their HDD space.

This is merely an explanation of the text you quoted, I do not necessarily agree with it.